# Adicionar delay/Timeout a um .hover()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ola estou com uma função .hover aonde eu gostaria que na segunda instancia (mouseleave) ocorre-se um delay para que o que esta dentro da função ocorra, ja tentei setar dentro da segunda função um setTimeout, tentei referenciar dentro do .hover, ".hover(function(){}, setTimeout(function(){});), mas ainda assim não consegui um resultado efetivo.
Função abaixo:

```js
    $("#lista-interface").on("mouseover", ".tarefas", function(){
        $(this).hover(function(){
            let divO = document.createElement("div");
            $(divO).attr({"class":("button" + " left"),});
            let divT = document.createElement("div");
            $(divT).attr({"class":("button" + " rigth"),});
            let divTR = document.createElement("div");
            $(divTR).attr({"class":("button" + " delete"),});
            $(this).append(divO);
            $(this).append(divT);
            $(this).append(divTR);
        }, function(){

            $("div").remove(".button, .left");
            $("div").remove(".button, .rigth");
            $("div").remove(".button, .delete");
            set
        });
    });
```

alguma ideia de como isso possa ser efeito, ou se teria alguma outra forma de eu conseguir o mesmo efeito.

Comment: Pq não usa `$("#lista-interface .tarefas").hover` direto sem ter que usar um `mouseover` antes?

Comment: Por que eu estava tendo conflitos com essa função pois a class .tarefas so aparece depois que a pagina é carregada por completo, ai eu precisei linkar o over a um item que ja se encontra inicialmente na pagina pra que quando ocorra o evento não tenha conflitos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colocar um evento dentro do outro não é uma boa prática porque ao chamar o primeiro, irá criar múltiplos listeners do segundo. Por exemplo, ao chamar o `mouseover`, irá criar múltiplos `.hover()`, ou seja, quando você chamar o `mouseover` pela segunda vez, irá disparar o `.hover()` 2 vezes, e assim consecutivamente.

Para resolver a questão do delay, você incluir o código da segunda função na função do `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $("div").remove(".button, .left");
   $("div").remove(".button, .rigth");
   $("div").remove(".button, .delete");
}, 2000); // executa após 2 segundos
```

Em relação ao problema descrito no início, eu sugeriria não utilizar `.hover()`. Você pode usar os dois eventos do `.hover()` de forma com que funcione mesmo se os elementos ainda não tiverem no DOM, basta usar um `if...else` verificando qual o evento foi disparado:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter mouseleave", "#lista-interface .tarefas", function(event){

     if(event.type == "mouseenter"){
         let divO = document.createElement("div");
         $(divO).attr({"class":("button" + " left"),});
         let divT = document.createElement("div");
         $(divT).attr({"class":("button" + " rigth"),});
         let divTR = document.createElement("div");
         $(divTR).attr({"class":("button" + " delete"),});
         $(this).append(divO);
         $(this).append(divT);
         $(this).append(divTR);
     }else if(event.type == "mouseleave"){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("div").remove(".button, .left");
            $("div").remove(".button, .rigth");
            $("div").remove(".button, .delete");
        }, 2000);
     }
});
```

Comment: Não sabia que poderia usar o on() dessa forma, agora uma duvida minha, o function(event) quando passado dessa forma o interpretador entende que o que esta sendo passado é um evento? ou se eu colocasse qualquer nome dentro do parenteses do function ele passaria o mesmo "valor" para a função.

Comment: Pode colocar qualquer nome sim.

Comment: Compreendo verificando o evento dessa forma eu acabei tendo um outro conflito veja, essa class .tarefas é atribuida a uma div que contem duas textareas, da forma que eu aprensentei anteriormente mesmo o mouse se encontrava sobre a textarea mas ainda no escopo da div os buttons eram exibidos, porem da forma com que me passou o delay começa a contar mesmo que o mouse esteja sobre a textarea, alguma ideia de como poderia resolver isso?

Comment: Vou analisar aqui pra vc....

Comment: Olha eu retirei o else if e deixei só o if no mouseleave e aparentemente esta funcionando muito bem, creio que possa ser conflitos com outra funções minhas pois sou novo com js e jquery, logo meu codigo ta uma bagunça então pode ser que seja algo aqui comigo mesmo.

Comment: Se tá funcionando blz... se der problema depois me chama aqui.